# Calculate alpha parameter for beta in R

Tags: r

How can I calculate the alpha value for P(x>a)=0.1 using R commands for a given Beta(3,2)?

I know there are `pbeta`, `qbeta` but none of them fits the problem as far as I know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `a <- qbeta(p, 3, 2)` solves P(x < a) = p. Then, note that P(x >= a) = 1 - P(x<a). So, you need to calculate `a <- qbeta(1 - p, 3, 2)`

Comment: thank you so much, for a quick confirm the answer is `a<-qbeta(0.9, 3, 2)` given that  P(x>a)=0.1